# Bootstrap 5 sass components are not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I have bootstrap 5 and all my design works great except the bootstrap components e.g. accordions, alerts, etc. do not work.

In these components it seems that bootstrap does not exist but all the sass files exist and all their values do not work.

He descargado bootstrap desde [aqui](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/download/)

The component of alert seems as here:

[image]

I used this link to bootstrap `<link href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is edit the link to bootstrap for this `<link href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`